# Disable all paste functions for the following vba code

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I'm running a target intersect method in excel to prevent a user from pasting over validation cells, problem is, I didn't account for all the paste methods, and pastespecial overrides the cell validations.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I14:J1000")) Is Nothing Then
    On Error Resume Next ' In case there's been no previous action
    ' Check if the last action was a paste
    If Left(Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1), 5) = "Paste" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Undo
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

I used the code below and binded it to Ctrl V, so that it matches the destination formatting, but it overrides the cell validation from the previous code:

```
Sub PasteWithDestinationFormatting()
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
End Sub
```

I'm assuming I need to change ="Paste" to a "PasteSpecial" but it didn't accomplish what I wanted it to do, most likely cause I didn't have the correct location of the PasteSpecial object.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why don't you **test your theory** (starting by googling the `Paste` and `PasteSpecial` methods)?  That being said, I'm unclear on what exactly you're doing but it seems like you're over-complicating something simple.

Comment: non-vba solution - lock the cells and protect the workbook.